# Centrar un input de material design lite

Tags: css, material-design-lite

Estoy intentanto que un `input` me quede centrado de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo entendido que para centrar un elemento en bloque debería utilizar `margin-left:auto` y `margin-right:auto` sin embargo, no obtengo el efecto que deseo.

Éste es mi código:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <style media="screen">
      .input-placa {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield input-placa">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="placa">Placa</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
    </div>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No obtienes el efecto deseado porque la clase `.mdl-textfield` hace que el `div` tenga un `display:inline-block` y entonces el método no funciona porque no es un bloque (con `display:block`).

La solución es sencilla: modificar el estilo que ya tienes en `.input-placa` para que también se considere un `block` (también funcionaría con el valor `inherit`):

```
.input-placa {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Si te fijas ahora sí que centra bien el campo a pantalla completa en un ordenador, pero falla cuando el tamaño es tableta o teléfono (como en el caso de la ventanita de abajo):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <style media="screen">
      .input-placa {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        display:block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield input-placa">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="placa">Placa</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"></div>
    </div>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Esto ocurre porque en el `grid` las columnas están definidas para pantalla grande (`mdl-cell--N-col`), pero no tienen definición para pantallas más pequeñas (`mdl-cell--N-col-tablet` y `mdl-cell--N-col-phone`).

Así que no vale sólo con centrar el elemento en la celda, sino que también tienes que hacer que las celdas se ajusten a una fila (y como está centrado en la celda del medio, se mantendrá centrado).

> Nota: como se indica en la [documentación](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/src/grid#introduction), el valor máximo de los valores por fila para pantalla grande es 12, para tableta es 8 y para teléfono es 4.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <style media="screen">
      .input-placa {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        display:block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--1-col-tablet mdl-cell--1-col-phone"></div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield input-placa">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="placa">Placa</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--1-col-tablet mdl-cell--1-col-phone"></div>
    </div>
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.1/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Tambíen muy oportuna para mi la aclaración de que el valor máximo por fila en tabletas es 8 y en telefono es 4, yo la verdad pensaba que era 12 para todas y se ajustaba automaticamente.